# How to deal with very complex codebase?

Tags: coding-style, code-quality, clean-code, complexity, code-reuse

I recently changed my job to a big MNC and the code I am exposed to is highly complicated, difficult to read and understand. Although it is divided in microservices and runs on local I have to keep running it on local step by step and many times the methods are tediously long and not just abstract with bunch of hacks around. I really hate pinging people many times to ask for clarifications to make changes to it. Solving a bug once took me 2 days. There are only 3 main APIs but they are very deep and nested and there are areas of code which only other devs know about.

How do we deal with such things as a developer? Really appreciate if anyone can share their thoughts on the same.

Comment: see also: [How do you dive into large code bases?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6395/31260)

Comment: If you can run locally and step through the code, you have most of what you need. Some things simply take time. And patience.

Comment: What you're asking is essentially how a significant percentage (if not outright majority) of us do our jobs. This is way too broad to be meaningfully answerable.

Comment: OP just boasts and wants extra praise from strangers. My last bug took tree working weeks to fix. It was in a somewhat familiar average complexity codebase within a single service.

Answer (score 2):

Get people to talk to you.

I would suggest several iterations of:

- Spend time identifying several places you do not understand.
- Call those who do in a short, precise meeting where they explain what is going on.
- Write your understandings up as documentation afterwards.
- Have them review your understandings.

You will probably need to spend quite a lot of time understanding this software before confidently be able to fix bugs in it.